# jquery Datatable: How can i pass the table row data to an onclick function

Tags: datatable

I have a datatable that has a delete button, when click the delete button i want to pass the values in the row to my sever to delete and also delete in on the row when the server responds with a success. How can i achieve getting the value of the row to the onclick function and also the tr element so i can delete it.

[image]

this is my present code:

```
model.initDataTable = function () {

    $('#datatables').DataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/admin/query/fibre",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                //process data before sent to server.
            }},
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name" : "ID", "title" : "ID"  },
            { "data": "name", "name" : "Name" , "title" : "Name"},
            { "class":"",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": "<button id='dltBtn' type=\"button\" class=\"btn purple-gradient btn-sm\">Delete</button>"},
            { "class":"",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": "<button id='viewBtn' type=\"button\" class=\"btn purple-gradient btn-sm\">Delete</button>"},

        ]




    } );


    $('#datatables tbody').on( 'click', '#dltBtn', function () {



    } );




};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use class instead of ID for the delete button, for example: `btn-delete`.

Then use the handler below.

```js
$('#datatables tbody').on('click', '.btn-delete', function (){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var data =  $('#datatables').DataTable().row($row).data();

   console.log('data', data);
   console.log('Record ID is', data['id']);

   // Add your code here   

});
```